# Ruby on Rails, PublicActivity. foreign key not inserted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems

I am using the PublicActivity gem to create an activity feed system. however "member_id" is never inserted into the "stories: table as a foreign key. If I remove the "belongs_to: member" the system will post, but the current member_id is never inserted. In the controller table you can see it never sends the member_id as a parameter (I am following a tutorial).

Also, can I just insert the current member_id into the table manually?

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :member

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  include PublicActivity::Model
    tracked
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
```

...

```
  has_many :stories

end

class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @stories = Story.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @story = Story.new
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
      flash[:success] = 'Your story was added!'
      redirect_to stories_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @story.update_attributes(story_params)
      flash[:success] = 'The story was edited!'
      redirect_to stories_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @story.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'The story was deleted!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Cannot delete this story...'
    end
    redirect_to stories_path
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def story_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def find_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

  before_action :load_activities, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit]

  private

  def load_activities
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order('created_at DESC').limit(20)
  end

end
```

migration:

```
class CreateStories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :stories do |t|

  t.column :title, :string, :default => ""
  t.belongs_to :member, index: true

  t.text :body



  t.text :tags
  t.integer :type
  t.integer :category
  t.string :image_path


  t.datetime :created_at, :null => false
  t.datetime :updated_at

  t.timestamps
end
end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :members
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
#resources :layouts
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

    resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]


resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]

resources :stories
#root to: 'stories#index'

end
```

Routes related to stories:

```
/stories(.:format)  
stories#index

POST    /stories(.:format)  
stories#create

new_story_path  GET /stories/new(.:format)  
stories#new

edit_story_path GET /stories/:id/edit(.:format) 
stories#edit

story_path  GET /stories/:id(.:format)  
stories#show

PATCH   /stories/:id(.:format)  
stories#update

PUT /stories/:id(.:format)  
stories#update

DELETE  /stories/:id(.:format)  
stories#destroy
```

Comment: Could you open rails console: `rails c --sandbox` and run `Story.inspect`? Also could you show us your `rake routes`?

Comment: Story.inspect
=> "Story(id: integer, title: string, member_id: integer, body: text, tags: text, type: integer, category: integer, image_path: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)"

Comment: Routes gives a bunch of outputs too much to place here

Comment: Just give the routes related to `StoriesController`. Btw. you have  member_id declared in the `Story` model.

Comment: Or show the `routes.rb` file with members and stories resources.

Comment: I updated the main post with the routes and route.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add current_member id in story table then in create action you can do it.either manually assign `@story.member_id = current_member.id` or more appropriate approach for this would be `@story = current_member.stories.build(story_params)`.

If you need to add a member id in story(not current_member id always but a different member) then send it from view. you can use `hidden_field` to send member_id as parameter with other form data and `white list` it in story params.

Comment: Okay, thanks, the current line is     @story = Story.new(story_params)
How do I add your (2nd) code in there? Most notably with the "new" tag